# How to use Jackson to deserialise

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

json object from REST service

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Chicago, IL, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Syracuse, NY, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,090 km",
                  "value" : 1090383
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "10 hours 21 mins",
                  "value" : 37242
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Using code from [JacksonInFiveMinutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#A.22Raw.22_Data_Binding_Example)

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map userData = mapper.readValue(webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(String.class);, Map.class);

Where:

```
webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(String.class);
```

returns the json from REST service

From Json I would like the 2 address properties as well as the distance property as well as the 2 status.

My hack attempt:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jnode = mapper.readValue(s, JsonNode.class);
jnode.findValue("distance").findValue("value") //
```

this gets me the value I am looking for.

Not sure if this is good way to go about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK to me, except that it would be safer to not chain those two `findValue()` calls together, as you could get a NPE if the JSON string doesn't contain the first one. From the JsonNode javadoc:

> `public abstract JsonNode findValue(String fieldName)`
>
> Method for finding a JSON Object field with specified name in this
>   node or its child nodes, and returning value it has. If no matching
>   field is found in this node or its descendants, **returns null**.

So I'd check the first `findValue()` result and if its not null, then perform the second `findValue()` (with logging to notify you if this happens).

Comment: Can you explain `findNode()` as I am not following?